# TyperError: urlpage.match(...) is null JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, url, null

I want to take a value from an URL an put it on an input.
So,

Normal URL: www.mysite.com

URL with value: www.mysite.com/mypage.php?variabletext

So, I want to extract ?variabletext (and, yes, it´s always a different text string)

I´m using this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var urlpage = window.location.href;
    regex = /http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/mypage.php\?([a-zA-Z]+)/;
    var texturl = urlpage.match(regex)[1]; 
    if(texturl !== null)
    {
    document.getElementById('idmyinput').value= texturl;
    }

});
```

Now the problem.

If i put a value, for example, *www.mysite.com/mypage.php?bob*

**It works well.**

But if it´s not a value, example, *www.mysite.com/mypage.php*

I receive this error:

**TyperError: urlpage.match(...) is null**

My idea is that only change the value of the input if the variable texturl has a value, aka, is not null.

Anyone can help me...?
Thanks a lot

Comment: the problem (error) is right at this point `[1]` since you have no fallback like `[1] || []` if there's no match ([1] is null)

Comment: Is this looking at the current page? You can use `location.search` to access the ? and everything after it. You can just check if it's length is greater than 1 and remove the first character with the `substring` function.

Answer (score 0):

If `urlpage.match(regex)` is `null` (that is, there is no match), then `urlpage.match(regex)[1]` will throw.

So you can use

```js
var match = urlpage.match(regex); 
if(match) {
  var texturl = match[1];
  // Use texturl
}
```

However, parsing URLs manually is a bad idea, use a [URLUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils) property instead. In this case, [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/search):

> The `URLUtils.search` property is a DOMString containing a `?`
>   followed by the parameters of the URL.

So you can use

```js
var texturl = location.sarch.substr(1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oriol... Works great! Here´s my final code, shorter and better :D  
 `code`var texturl = location.search.substr(1);
 if(texturl) {
document.getElementById('myinput').value= texturl;
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
 str =str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"");
str = str.replace(/httpwwwmysitecommypagephp/g,"");
```